# TikZ Issue With Function Plotting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create this simple TikZ plot of a quadratic function. But the code does not compile, and the error is detected at the part where I introduce the function. What is wrong with it?

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=1,yscale=1]

\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Car};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
\draw [domain=0:2] plot (\x, {2.5\x*\x});

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Furthermore, how is it possible to put two TikZ plots side by side on the same line? I have not been able to do this so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX SE! Next time, please post a **complete** [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

You are missing an `*`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=1,yscale=1]

    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Car};
    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
    \draw [domain=0:2] plot (\x, {2.5*\x*\x});% missing *

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]

## EDIT

To stop the function exceeding certain boundaries without having to recalculate the domain, you could clip the plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=1,yscale=1]
    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Car};
    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,0) |- (2.1,2) |- cycle;
      \draw [domain=0:2] plot (\x, {2.5*\x*\x});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: clipped plot]

You can adjust the clipping path if you want slightly different restrictions.

Comment: Great, thanks! I will be sure to post a MWE next time. Also, could you please answer the other part of the question?

Comment: @user11629 See edited answer.

Comment: What does the word "cycle" perform in this? And if you put two plots side by side, is there a command to line them up? at the bottom axes?

Comment: `cycle` is just shorthand for 'and back to wherever this path started'. So it completes the rectangle. I could have repeated the first coordinate instead. Probably the two plots question should be a new question so that you can include code for two plots.